# How to print a clickable string in console which will open a link to a website in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hyperlink, pycharm

When I print a normal link for example " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask " console automatically recognizes it as a link and redirects me to url when clicked. I want to print String for example "StackOverFlow" and I want it to be highlighted as hyperlink and redirect me to link specified above.

[image: hon]

Comment: Pretty vague. But assuming you want to see `StackOverflow` highlighted and as a clickable link in your terminal ? I am not sure if it is possible, unless if your terminal understands some markup language

Comment: @hansolo yes I want that

Comment: Are you asking for the terminal, or within pycharm?

Comment: It depends on your terminal emulator. See https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda

Comment: the main reason why I want to do this, is to copy that console output and put it into a excel spreadsheet. where people will be able to view just name and not a full url.

Comment: If your just looking to be able to copy it into excel, why not just print out the excel formatting. It's been awhile, but I believe it's `=HYPERLINK(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, "Stack Overflow")`

Comment: @TheLazyScripter oh nice solution but the formula isnt working,

Comment: @TheLazyScripter It needed ""-s for url too

Comment: Ah there ya go!

Comment: @TheLazyScripter It didn't answer my question but solved the problem, Thanks ^^

Comment: Apologies for that. But the answer would rely on the interpreter you are using and whether it offered any sort of markup for raw output. Some like pycharm and eclipse have plugins that may achieve this but without further information and research it's unknown!

Comment: @TheLazyScripter no just meant that i actually asked the wrong question, but ill still leave it here maybe someone will know the answer and others may need to use it.